# How to classify xsd:elements in xsd:sequence in WSDL file?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have a wsdl file that describes a cxf web service.
while there is many input parameters, i am asked to classify them in WSDL file to make it clearer and to simplify its understanding.

there is a part of the wsdl generated file:

```
 <xs:complexType name="eventObject">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="computerName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="displayName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="identifier" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="inMaintenanceMode" type="xs:boolean"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                ...
                ...
                ...
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="state" type="xs:string"/>

            </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
```

So i want to regroup the first, the third and the fourth parameters in a category named computerDState and the rest in an other category **without defining java classes to regroup them.**

Please help!